# Update realm IgnoredProperties While App Running

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, google-maps, realm

```
class place :Object{
    @objc dynamic var name : String = ""
    @objc dynamic var address :String = ""
    @objc dynamic var lat :Double = 0.0
    @objc dynamic var long :Double = 0.0
    var marker = GMSMarker()
    var cllCorrdinate : CLLocationCoordinate2D {
       return CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat, longitude: long)  
   }
}
```

when i add a place to an array of FirstViewController

```
let place = Place()
place.name = "123"
place.address = "123 street"
place.lat = lat
place.long = lon

let marker = GMSMarker()
marker.position = place.cllCorrdinate
marker.icon = UIImage(imageLiteralResourceName: "123")
place.marker = marker
place.marker.map = mapView
saveToRealm(place: place)
```

I am Sharing data between two ViewController with singleton class and keep updating it through viewWillDisappear and viewDidApear

```
class anotherController:UITableViewController{
var places:List<PLace>?
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let place = places[indexPath.row]
    let marker = place.marker    
}}
```

Value of marker always showing nil.
is it possible to update ignore property only while app is running ?
places are saving and updating fine in realm

Comment: I am not sure what you're asking but if you create a `marker` in code and assign it to an unmanaged property in realm, it will not be stored in realm. e.g. in the `place` object you're got this var `var marker = GMSMarker()` which is not managed by realm so therefore will not be populated when the object is loaded into memory.

Comment: @Jay thanks for edit and comment. i want to modify marker from another view controller as well.right now and making array of markers and using it in another view Controller.is there any simple way to do that rather than taking care of two array separately

Comment: There are 100 ways to modify variables. You can pass the variables between controllers, use a segue, reload the data in each etc. It really depends on what the end result is. Are you displaying both view controllers concurrently or is this a master->detail setup?

Comment: both view controllers are master..both can read write and modify..hence marker is ignoredproperty so i have to manually update both objects in both viewcontrollers.

Comment: Hmm. Let me re-ask the question;  Are you using and showing two view controllers *at the same time* on the same screen? There's just not enough info in the question for us to understand what you're doing or what the question actually is; are you updating the realm object within a .write? If so, Realm results will be updated automatically and the object will reflect the new state anywhere it's used. I would suggest re-thinking what's being asked and clarify the question with additional information to help us understand the use case. I would also suggest not using a a singleton pattern this way.

Comment: i have two controllers of UITabvc 1st is mapview 2nd is tableview. i add a place from mapviewcontroller(1st) and pin a marker.place is saving to realm directly.i am populating tableviewcontroller(2nd) with realm places.if i delete place from 2nd vc, place is deleting from realmdatabase as well.but when i come back to 1st vc marker is still showing.if it make sense

Comment: Yeah - it makes sense but that's a coding error outside the scope of this question and would take a significant amount of time to view a lot of your code to determine that issue. If you have a realm results object and an object is deleted from realm, it will no longer be part of those results - that's how results work; results are live views of what's in realm. If it's not being removed then you may have stored the object in an array or some other non-results element that's disconnected from Realm.